# How to set a dropdownlist item as selected in Angularjs2 Beta

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using angularjs 2 and typescript, where I have a dynamically loaded dropdown list.

```
 <select name="" tabindex="1">
    <option *ngFor="#option of options" value="{{option.value}}" > 
        {{option.text}} 
    </option>
 </select>
```

this is my data

```
options: option[] = [
        { text: 'Deny access to this web address',value: 1 },
        { text: 'Sample banned content list2', value: 2},
        { text: 'Sample banned content list3', value: 3}
    ];
```

How can I set option[0] as 'selected' (`<option value='1' selected>Deny access to this web address </option>`) This is the expected output. How can I set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <select name="" tabindex="1">
    <option *ngFor="#option of options; #i=index" value="{{option.value}}" [selected]="i == 0 ? true : null" > 
        {{option.text}} 
    </option>
  </select>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/odwILkNIHOpEKMcDGqKb?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get that I need `<option value='1' selected>Deny access to this web address </option>` as my output.